# Can you catch Keldeo in Pokemon X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Can you tell me what event you can get a Keldeo in?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot catch a Keldeo in Pokemon XY.

But there are currently only 2 ways to get Keldeo:

1. **Trade**: Be it with a friend, acquaintance or passer-by, you can get a Keldeo if someone's willing to trade one to you.
2. **Transfer from PokeBank**: There have been a few events throughout the world during the past two years where Keldeo were being given. You can find a list [here](http://serebii.net/events/dex/647.shtml).

Unless there's another event where you can get Keldeo in Pokemon XY, those two above ways are the only ways to get Keldeo.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to get event-only pokemon from the GTS anymore. They cannot be uploaded to the GTS for trade, and (apparently) it will not let you complete trades with them. The only way to trade them would seem to be using the PSS Friends/Acquaintances/Passersby lists.

Answer (score 0):

GTS trade doesn't allow special or mythical pokemon trades anymore, the only free way to get Keldeo is trading with PSS friends, acquaintances, and passersby.