# Can I trade PowerSave/ActionReplay Event Pokemon with Passersby on the PSS?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

So I will soon have a PowerSave/ActionReplay device and I want to use wondercard codes that I know come with the device to get things like Genesect, Keldeo, Mew, etc. I would then like to give these Pokémon as gifts to random people I find on the PSS.

I understand that I cannot trade these on the GTS, but will I be able to trade them with random PSS people? Is there something special I'll have to do to make it possible? Or would I damage people's games by trying to do this?

I found this link while Googling, but it's for XY, and it doesn't mention anything about PowerSave devices: [Can you catch Keldeo in Pokémon X\Y?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166754/can-you-catch-keldeo-in-pokemon-x-y)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can trade powersaved Pokemon online with random Passersby.
As long as they're 100% legit, of course.

For example, you can't trade "shinyfied" Legendaries that are actually *shiny-locked* or Pokemon with unreleased hidden abilities.
Another example are Pokemon with hacked Pokeball (Apricorn usually) on Pokemon with their hidden ability. Those balls were available only on HGSS and hidden abilities didn't exist in 4th gen.

And obviously you can't trade unreleased Pokemon, like *Volcanion* and *Hoopa*.